# Bulging of Faces

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to model the shoulder of a character ,and for that I need to bulge the center of a rectangular face.How should I approach this?I'm using **Blender 2.79**.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135809/edit) link at the bottom of your question (i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand exactly what you're talking about. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. It will keep it all quads. Just mark the face you want a bulge on and Inset (I). Raise it with CTRL as described by the tool hints.

[image]